# kdb: does a leading plus sign mean a Q table?

Tags: kdb

I often see output like
`` +`col1`col2`col3!(,`a`b`c;,{x+1};,()!()) ``. I suspect it means a table, but wasn't able to find documentation on this syntax.

What does the leading `+` mean? Could someone provide a link to a reference page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's notation in K, the language Q operations are built in. `+` is the flip operator when used monadically, and internally tables are referred to as Flips.

In Q, `flip` is built from this and the `:` operator, which forces the `+` to be interpreted monadically. Similarly for the `where` keyword:

```
q)flip
+:
q)where
&:
```